# How to implement React route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new on React, i've got a problem about react route. Let's say i have email verification page and register page, and this is my route code

```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/register/emailverification" component={EmailVerification} />
    </Switch>
```

when i go to

> localhost/register/emailverification

i want it to render email verifation page but i dont know why its render register page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
<Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
<Route exact path="/register/emailverification" component={EmailVerification} />
```

If you only want to render one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to use keyword `'exact'` in all the `'Route'` components or else it will load both parent as well child routers which are subsets of your browser url.
Also it is always better to add a default router with path = `'/'`

```
<Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
```